# Book Lovers / Book worms with different words?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for synonym of Book Lovers, people who like read books, like Book Enthusiast, Book Buffs, but combination of words should also sound good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard term is **bibliophile**.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliophilia):

> The classic bibliophile is one who loves to read, admire and collect books, often amassing a large and specialized collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another term that's existed since 1583 according to Merriam Webster: BOOKMAN: a person who has a love of books and especially of reading.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookman

And another one according to Oxord Dictionary: BIBLIOLATER (first known use: 1847): A person who extravagantly admires a book or books ("Above all I am a bibliolater: I can read anything and everything under the sun.")