# Any language of person who enjoys reading or loves reading and loves books

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is a word or definition of someone who loves to read?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book Lovers / Book worms with different words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235067/book-lovers-book-worms-with-different-words)

Comment: bibliophile . . . .

Comment: I don't see how this question is "Off topic"... duplicate perhaps, but it's a clear `single-word-request`.

Comment: Ah, now I see: From the tag defnition:
> This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Bookworm

Is the word you're looking for.

[Dictionary definition](http://dictionary.com/browse/bookworm?s=t%20/)

Answer (score 2):

Bookworm is good, but may have some subtle negative connotations.

[Bibliophile](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bibliophile) might be a better choice, but, as Vector points out in the comments, this is really someone who loves books (like a collector) and is not necessarily someone who loves to read them.

Comment: The possible negative connotation of bookworm did occur to me, yes. But  _bibliophile_ refers to someone who loves books - a collector for example - not necessarily reading. _biblio_ is from the Greek and means "book".

Comment: Great point - I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks